# Android Volley Runs only once displaying only one Notification - Firebase Cloud Messaging using PHP / Volley

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-volley

I am working on an android chat app using firebase. Everything works fine except push notification. I have googled and read almost every post concerning the issue but still haven't figured out the solution!

Issue: On a fresh installation of the app to the device! I get the notification (ONLY ONCE FIRST TIME) then after that, there is no notification displayed whatsoever. Volley returns a success message "Multicast id remains the same for each success message and even the message-id remains the same for each success message" wondering it has to do with the problem! please have a look at the below code:

1) MY PHP SCRIPT RUNNING ON MY OWN WEB ADDRESS (APP SERVER):

```
<?php

     define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAeaFcZdA:APA91bFqhLc..............' );
     $token = $_GET["token"];

     $title = $_POST["title"];
     $notification = $_POST["message"];
     $msg =
     [
        'message'   => $notification,
        'title'   => $title,

     ];
     $fields = 
     [
        'to'  => $token,
        'data'      => $msg
     ];

     $headers = 
     [
       'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
       'Content-Type: application/json'
     ];
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
     curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
     $result = curl_exec($ch );
      if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
     curl_close( $ch );
     echo $result;
    ?>
```

2) My MessagingService (Firebase) to get Notifications, Since I get the first notification, I believe its configured properly!

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Timber.i("From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        //Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Timber.i("Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            sendNotification(data);
        }
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Timber.i("Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            sendNotification(data);
        }
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        sendNotification(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        Timber.i("MyToken:    " + token);
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference usersdRef = database.getReference("users");
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            usersdRef.child(user.getUid()).child("tokens").setValue(token);
        }
    }


    private void sendNotification(Map<String, String> messageBody) {

        String myTitle = messageBody.get("title");
        final int not_nu = generateRandom();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatMessageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", myTitle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        ChatUserModel.chatWith = myTitle;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, not_nu /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.marker)
                        .setContentTitle(messageBody.get("title"))
                        .setContentText(messageBody.get("message"))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(not_nu /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    public int generateRandom() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
    }}
```

3) My Chat Activity where I am sending the message to another user. 
   getOtherToken = other user token id to whom I will send the message

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                String currentDate = sdf.format(new Date());
                String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

                if (!messageText.equals("")) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("message", messageText);
                    map.put("user", user.getDisplayName());
                    map.put("timetoshow", currentTime);
                    map.put("dateStamp", currentDate);
                    usersmRef.child(reference1).push().setValue(map);
                    usersmRef.child(reference2).push().setValue(map);
                    messageArea.setText("");
                    sendNotificationToappServer(getOtherToken, user.getDisplayName(), messageText);
                    Timber.i("GetOtherTOken: " + user.getDisplayName() + " | " + getOtherToken + " | " + messageText);
                }


            }
        });
```

4) My Volley Method in the Same ChatActivity.java as above where I send String Request to my App Server, the token here is of the user who will receive the message!

```
    public void sendNotificationToappServer(String token, String title, String notification) {
        String SERVER_ADDRESS = "https://www.mywebsite/notification.php?token=";

        RequestQueue requestQueue;

        // Instantiate the cache
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

        // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
        requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

        // Start the queue
        requestQueue.start();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SERVER_ADDRESS + token,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatMessageActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Timber.i("Volley: %s", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatMessageActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Timber.i("Volley Error: " + error.toString());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("title", title);
                params.put("message", notification);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

5) My Volley Response recorded in Android Studio which is a success, For the first time, it delivers push notification but not after that until fresh install!
[image: Volley Response]

Anything if required other than above! please let me know. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue! Well, I found out the problem was cache management due to volley. Before posting a new queue request, clearing the cache will fix the issue!
`queue.getCache().clear();`

Also, I preferred using singleton class for Volley. Here is the updated code for sendNotificationToappServer method above:

```
    public void sendNotificationToappServer(String token, String title, String notification) {
        String SERVER_ADDRESS = "https://www.mywebsite/notification.php?token=";

//         Get a RequestQueue
                RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(ChatMessageActivity.this).
                 getRequestQueue();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SERVER_ADDRESS + token,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatMessageActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Timber.i("Volley: %s", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatMessageActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Timber.i("Volley Error: " + error.toString());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("title", title);
                params.put("message", notification);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };

queue.getCache().clear();
        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

The PHP code in the question above works perfectly! so if you are looking for PHP script for firebase Cloud messaging App server for one on one messaging, go for it!